# onServiceConnected is not calling

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to call this method but it is not getting call

```
ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){  onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
```

due to which i am getting below error.
Its was working fine when it was on Fragment but when i try to run it on AppCompatActivity its not working.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.kpgames.testmusicplayer.MusicService.setSong(int)' on a null object reference
----------

       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4023)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4783)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19887)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4018)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4783) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19887) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.kpgames.testmusicplayer.MusicService.setSong(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.kpgames.testmusicplayer.MainActivity.songPicked(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4018) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4783) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19887) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements MediaPlayerControl{
private ArrayList<Song> songList;
private ListView songView;
private MusicController controller;

private MusicService musicSrv;
private Intent playIntent;
private boolean musicBound=false;
private boolean paused=false, playbackPaused=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    songView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    getSongList();
    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
        public int compare(Song a, Song b){
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

    SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
    songView.setAdapter(songAdt);
    setController();


}


//connect to the service
private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder)service;
        //get service
        musicSrv = binder.getService();
        //pass list
        musicSrv.setList(songList);
        musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
   // if(playIntent==null){
        playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);
    //}
}


public void songPicked(View view){
    musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
    musicSrv.playSong();
    if(playbackPaused){
        setController();
        playbackPaused=false;
    }
    controller.show(0);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_shuffle:
            musicSrv.setShuffle();
            break;
        case R.id.action_end:
            stopService(playIntent);
            musicSrv=null;
            System.exit(0);
            break;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(playIntent);
    musicSrv=null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void getSongList() {
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

private void setController(){
    controller = new MusicController(this);
    controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playNext();
        }
    }, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playPrev();
        }
    });
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.song_list));
    controller.setEnabled(true);
}

private void playNext(){
    musicSrv.playNext();
    if(playbackPaused){
        setController();
        playbackPaused=false;
    }
    controller.show(0);
}

private void playPrev(){
    musicSrv.playPrev();
    if(playbackPaused){
        setController();
        playbackPaused=false;
    }
    controller.show(0);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    musicSrv.go();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    playbackPaused=true;
    musicSrv.pausePlayer();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound && musicSrv.isPng())
    return musicSrv.getDur();
    else return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound && musicSrv.isPng())
    return musicSrv.getPosn();
    else return 0;
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    paused=true;
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(paused){
        setController();
        paused=false;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    controller.hide();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    musicSrv.seek(pos);
}


@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    if(musicSrv!=null && musicBound)
    return musicSrv.isPng();
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

**This is service code**

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {


//media player
private MediaPlayer player;
//song list
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
//current position
private int songPosn;
private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
private String songTitle = "";
private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;
private boolean shuffle = false;
private Random rand;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return musicBind;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    return false;
}

public void onCreate() {
    //create the service
    super.onCreate();
 //initialize position
    songPosn = 0;
//create player
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    initMusicPlayer();
    rand = new Random();

}

public void initMusicPlayer() {
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);

}

public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs) {
    songs = theSongs;
}

public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
    MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android call onBind() method just once for every Service. If you bind/unbing to it later, method .onRebind() is called

Comment: This is the only method where i am binding services. can you help me how to do that.